Understanding 今回は出直すとする
From Quintessential Quintuplet ch. 5,

Their study session appears to be cut short and he says「今回は出直すとする」. I have trouble piece together meanings of the words. I don't understand what 出直す might mean here. I thought it meant "back to square one" but if that's the case then 今回 would be better understood as "next time" not "this time" which is unlikely...?

"Back to square one" isn't a bad translation but for this specific case I think a simple "try again" is better. "今回" because Futaro is using it here as a "[give it up for now but] try again next time".
